# When using Telnet, why it doesn't ask for the password?

Tags: packet-tracer

The first thing the prompt asks is the console's password. Shouldn't it be asking for the telnet's password first? Below is the code.

```
line vty 0 4
password LINE
login
```

AFAIK, "login" isn't needed, but I just did. And then I saved it. I am using packet tracer.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: If you think that when you console into a Cisco device that it asks for the telnet password, you are mistaken. The console and VTY lines are for completely different things, and one has no effect on the other.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're mixing up console access and telnet access. The statement you're showing only works for telnet access. If you want to set a password for console access, you need to configure it like this:

```
line con 0
password MYPASS
login
```

Comment: My problem is it doesn't ask for the password of the telnet, that is why I showed that. Before it asks for the console password, I am expecting that the prompt would ask for the telnet password first.

Comment: You're assuming a lot and aren't providing a lot of details. Please add your entire configuration to the original question, and describe in detail how you're connecting to the router.

Answer (score 0):

It may be packet tracer. It's not perfect. I've never used telnet with packet tracer. Your command looks good and it should have prompted you.

If you want to try another way do
    Line vty 0 4
    Login local
This will use the same password you set for the switch password. The term local refers to the local TACASAS database in Cisco devices or Radius server if your using it to log into the switch or router.